# Error after updating Entity from Database: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Has anyone ever seen something like this:

I've taken over coding an existing solution, which was running along just fine until I added a new table to the database, and then updated the entity from the DB.  Everything seemed fine, until run-time, when all of a sudden I get this error on the home controller:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

From the stack trace...

```
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Response.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
```

The thing is, the home controller didn't change.  It never did have a parameterless constructor.  Further, all the references to it take parameters, so I'm not even sure where/why it thinks it needs a constructor that is parameterless.

Really confused.

Let me know if I need to add something more to help solve this.  I'm kinda shooting in the dark 'cause I've never seen something like before.

**EDIT:**

Here's the constructor:

```
        public HomeController([Dependency("ImageUploadPath")] string imageUploadPath, 
            IPermissions permissions, 
            IResponseEntitiesFactory responseEntities, 
            IResponseWebConfiguration responseWebConfiguration,
            ILog log)
            : base(imageUploadPath, permissions, responseWebConfiguration)
        {
            _responseEntitiesFactory = responseEntities;
            _responseWebConfiguration = responseWebConfiguration;
            _log = log;
        }
```

**EDIT #2:**

The soluiton is using the Unity DI framework.  Here's IUnityContainer ...

```
public class Bootstrapper
{

public static IUnityContainer BootstrapUnity()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bootstrapper)));
        var log = container.Resolve<ILog>();

        container.RegisterType<IResponseQueueConfiguration, ResponseQueueConfiguration>();
        var configuration = container.Resolve<IResponseQueueConfiguration>();

        container.RegisterType<IMessageDispatcherManager, MessageDispatcherManager>();
        container.RegisterType<ResponseTimeHelper, ResponseTimeHelper>(new InjectionConstructor(log)); // hint for unity to default to the parameter less constructor (it tries to default to the IResonseEntities version!)
        container.RegisterType<IActivityQueue, MSMQActivityQueue>(new InjectionConstructor(configuration.QueueName));
        container.RegisterType<IActivityService, LeadActivityService>();
        container.RegisterType<IDispositionDiagnosticService, DispositionDiagnosticService>();
        container.RegisterType<IHttpPoxService, HttpPoxService>(new InjectionConstructor(configuration.UrbanScienceDispositionService, log));
        container.RegisterType<ICreateWorkflowTasksService, CreateWorkflowTasksService>();
        container.RegisterType<INewLeadNotifications, NewLeadNotifications>();


        container.RegisterType<IResponseEntities, ResponseEntities>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterInstance<IResponseEntitiesFactory>(new SimpleResponseEntitiesFactory(() => new ResponseEntities()));
        container.RegisterInstance(container.Resolve<IResponseEntitiesFactory>().Create());

        container.RegisterType<ITokenReplacementService, TokenReplacementService>();
        container.RegisterType<IMessageProcessor, SendEmailMessageProcessor>("sendemail");
        container.RegisterType<IMessageProcessor, SendNewLeadNotificationsMessageProcessor>("sendnewleads");
        container.RegisterType<ITokenReplacementService, TokenReplacementService>();
        container.RegisterType<ISmtpConfiguration, SmtpConfiguration>();

        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor definition and tell if you use any DI framework?

Comment: Agree with raderick, sounds like the symptom of a DI problem to me.

Comment: Yes, there is a DI framework.   I'll edit the OP to show the constructor.

Comment: Very likely you have your DI misconfigured. Try removing parameters from constructor one by one to determine which parameter causes this issue.

Comment: Ok, I'l give that a shot and report back.  I've taken over this solution from a previous developer, and DI frameworks are new to me.

Comment: @raderick, how do I go about removing parameters?  If I remove one, it won't build.  Not sure of the process here.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston for instance you remove IPermissions permissions from HomeController constructor and pass null into base constructor instead of permissions. Same for IResponseEntitiesFactory responseEntities - you remove it from HomeController constructor and remove private field assignment: _responseEntitiesFactory = responseEntities;. All you need is to build project and verify, that your execution comes inside the constructor of HomeController when you call its methods without specific parameter passed to constructor.

Comment: If I do that, I can't compile because every reference to this controller now has the incorrect number of parameters.  Regardless, I am fairly certain that IResponseEntitiesFactory is the problem, because this is the interface which represents the data entity.  But, I don't know what to do with that knowledge.  You said, "Very likely you have your DI misconfigured".  Can you expound on this?

Comment: You can take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/raderick/5db62f64c1e0f3861e4a . About DI misconfiguration - DI is used to inject your interface implementations to classes, that are automatically created by DI container. Controllers are created using DI in your case. To inject an implementation, you have to register it in DI container somewhere - implementation depends on DI tool used. Here's a short example for castle.windsor: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md

Comment: so, when I use your example //without  IResponseEntitiesFactory, I get this error when trying to build.. "The best overload for 'HomeController' does not have a parameter named 'responseEntities'"

Comment: You can remove that paremeter passed to constructor in places it's called, if there are not too many. Or you can try leave existing constructor + add the ones I mentioned to see if any of them work. Otherwise you will have to investigate your DI configuration to find what component was not registered.

Comment: Unity is the DI framework, if that makes any difference. This DI stuff is new to me.  How would I go about investigate my DI configuration to find what component was not registered?
  I'll try adding your suggestions as overloads.

Comment: Find IUnityContainer usages in your project, where there's a variable of this type and methods .RegisterType<T1, T2>(), .RegisterInstance are called. You should verify that all of parameters passed in constructor are registered in any way. For more specific code check article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx with header "A Real-World Example"

Comment: thanks!  See most recent edit in OP.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I don't see registrations for `IPermissions`, `IResponseWebConfiguration` and `imageUploadPath`. There's either another registration file used, or they are not registered.

You can add `container.ResolveType<T>` for each of the types I mentioned in the place where your registrations happen after the last registration and check, if any exception is thrown. Also you can manually check container in debug and see all the registrations for your project and determine what is missing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  Question I can't get my head around:  Why would this have been working up to the point were I add a table in the DB and then update the model from the DB?

Comment: If you roll back your changeset with this table, does your code work? There might be either another change that broke this, or your tables are somehow messing with your class DI registration/instantiation cycle. What does "add a table to DB" mean? Just SQL code that's unrelated to your app, or did you create some infrastructure inside your app like repository or something similar?

Comment: I literally added a table via SSMS. Then I went into the .edmx file, did a right click, and selected 'Update Model from Database'.  This solution uses the DB First method of Linq to Entities.  I'll try and roll that change back and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, so if I go into Solution Explorer, go to Changes, find the .edmx file (ResponseEntities.edmx) and do an undo, then the error at runtime goes away.  Interesting.  I'm going to re-do the changes and compare.

Comment: You definitely need to make a diff for this changeset and see if changes somehow affect classes that take part in DI workflow. If some of child classes that are used for example by implementation of  IResponseEntitiesFactory  cannot be instantiated, it obviously won't be able to instantiate the parent - IResponseEntitiesFactory implementation

Comment: Well, I seem to have it working, although I don't really understand why.  I rolled back the changes from adding the new table.  Then I did re-added the table to the model (by updating the .edmx file from database), then I did a compare.  For some reason EF was making a lot of changes not associated with just that table.  I rolled back all changes not associated with this one table, and then ran the app again.  It worked.  Still not sure what caused the issue, but at least for now I have done what I needed to do, and I can move forward.

Comment: It might have rolled back some of the changes done manually to entities you operate. Main indicator of the place that causes issue - changes in constructor of the class.